# How performance can change using greedy LINQ operators?

Tags: performance, linq, c#-4.0

Is it performant wise to use greedy LINQ operators such as `ToList,ToLookUp,Distinct` etc?

What would be a best practice(s) for LINQ query execution?
You often use for your objects `List<>` or making all your objects lists to `IEnumerable<>`. I know the latest gives more flexibility.

When working with memory (LINQ to Objects) it's ok to always use deffered loading, cause you can access it whenever you need without fear that tha data changed, added or inserted as the reference will execute the query as soon as you need access. But this changes with database LINQ queries such LINQ to EF.

Would like a StackOverflow users opinion.

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "ok to always use [deffered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deferred) [sic] loading". Suppose you've got a `.Select()` that does complicated calculations that take a few milliseconds to complete, and you plan on iterating the resulting sequence a few thousand times. Then you should think seriously about capturing the results with `ToList`, so you're not doing those calculations over and over. (Of course, if the results take a lot of memory, you might opt for the speed hit in exchange for memory. Like everything, it's about tradeoffs.)

Comment: Great comment Joe, good point.....so you mean ToList should be used in cases where you use the "Select()" operator many times in the same list!

Comment: interesting read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162442/converting-ienumberablet-to-listt-on-a-linq-result-huge-performance-loss

Comment: ReSharper actually tries to warn you when you will iterate over an IEnumerable multiple times, which is one of the normal times you might want to ToList() something. As with many things, however, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be a best practice(s) for LINQ query execution?

A List may be accessed by index, a Lookup may be accessed by Key.  These types are obviously serializable across a WCF boundary.  A deferred IEnumerable doesn't do these things well.

For EF or LinqToSql, one must run their queries before the DataContext or whatever holds the SqlConnection gets disposed.

---

In my code, I use deferred IEnumerables only for method scoped variables when convenient.  I use List for properties (sometimes the property constructs the List, but usually it's just backed by an instance) and method return types.  Since I'm doing comparatively expensive things (like accessing the database or using WCF), the performance of eagerly executing in-memory Linq queries has never been an issue.

The final authority on any performance question is: `how does it measure?`